# ID Questions - Time to update the Guidance to include Image ID?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, identify

The inflow of Image ID questions continues unabated and our current guidance does not mention these **specifically**.

It's my understanding that the current 'rule' is that these are off-topic as not meeting site quality standards and are of neglible future value...right?

However the closure 'notice' is not explicit regarding Images.

> "Identification questions must contain sufficient detail to meet the site's quality standards and should not be about a commercial or music video. For help writing a good identification question, see: [Identify-This-X Questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Nor...in the provided link is there any specific reference to Image ID.

> Identification questions are currently on-topic for this site with the exception of commercials and music videos. Please try to show effort and give as much detail as possible:

So, can we amend the wording to include a specific reference to Image IDs?

Perhaps...

> Identification questions must contain sufficient detail to meet the site's quality standards and should not be about a commercial, music video **or consist only of an image**. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

and

> Identification questions are currently on-topic for this site with the exception of commercials, music videos and questions **consisting only of an image for detail**. Please try to show effort and give as much detail as possible.

Thoughts.

Comment: I'm ok with this, because it will also include questions that want to id an actor via an image, which is off-topic as well as low quality

Comment: @DForck42 Yes, this would encompass Movie / Actor / Episode IDs... **anything ** that is just an image and "Please find X for me".

Comment: Yet you complain about this for a question that's clearly does not ***consist of only an image***... you are not consistent with it.

Comment: @cde I'm not sure which question you are referring to.

Comment: I'm guessing this one - http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67051/identifying-the-albino-pirate-in-pan-2015. Arguably borderline that one... I went back and forth on that one..but that's actually closed for a *different reason* than that under discussion here.

Comment: You voted as ID, the mod bizarrely closed it as trivia. His reason overrode yours for the close text.

Comment: Okay, I'll set this straight here. I can see who voted as what and *noone* there voted as ID, as can also be seen from the close message itself, which includes all users who voted that way behind the actual reason.

Comment: I did mention Image ID questions in the comments just for reference but voted as a trivia question. The actor **does** appear on IMDB...but the OP didn't recognise him. As I said, I went back and forth on that one. However, not the point I'm trying to make here.

Comment: Are there *any* ID questions which *contain* an image which are acceptable?  I should imagine reverse image search would take care of the lot of them....

Comment: @Wildcard Odd you should ask...this [**one**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67868/does-kellan-lutz-portray-a-saxon-archer-in-king-arthur-2004) **doesn't** have image but might benefit from one. But then it becomes "Prove this **isn't** someone" ..which is actually worse I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the overwhelming support for this proposal, the respective sections in the help center and the close-reason have been ammended as proposed.

Comment: Yay! An excellent step forward.